# git flow: merge from remote develop branch, and see changes in feature branch?

Tags: git-flow

I'm using git flow.

We have develop branched from master, and I have feature/INF-824 branched from develop.

One of my coworkers has added a change to develop that's relevant to INF-824.

How can I merge his changes into my copy of develop, and see them in feature/INF-824?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cherry pick the change from the develop branch.

```
git cherry-pick <commit-ish>
```

Commit-ish would be the SHA1-ID of the commit you want in your feature branch.

The other option would be to use rebase on your feature branch

```
git rebase feature branch
```

This might be better solution as you'll be merging your feature back in develop anyway on finishing the feature branch.